# How to cast/convert values from JSON?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My background is all in dynamic languages for many years, so reasoning about how static typed languages get data from JSON where the key/values can be different types is becoming an issue that really has me stuck. Here's an example of the data I have:

```
{
    "par": 4,
    "level": [0,1,0,1,1, 0,1,0,1,1, 0,1,0,1,1, 0,1,0,1,1, 0,1,0,1,1]
}
```

And I want to get this into some local variables like these

```
int par;
List<bool> levelData;
```

I'm using MiniJSON.cs to do the parsing, and it gives me back `Dictionary<string, object>` but I can't figure out how to get the par and level values from that and convert them to the different types they actually represent.

Comment: Well if you look at the contents of the dictionary in the debugger, what does it show you? I suspect it may well be an `int` for `par` and an `int[]` for `level`... but that's just a guess.

Comment: You will fetch the data like this `int par = (int)jsonDictionary["par"]` which retievees it by key and casts it to the correct type. You might have to do a bit of trial and error debugging to work out what the actual type of data is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with trying to convert to `List<int>` was that MiniJSON parses integers into `Int64` and `int` is 32-bit, so the conversion won't be allowed implicitly because of data loss. Converting to a list of `Int64` worked!

```
List<Int64> cells = (List<Int64>)data["level"];
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide a "decoder" that transforms the dictionary into a typed data structure. This is especially obvious since you are using `0` and `1` to represent boolean values.

Suppose the class `SomeClass` holds your typed data. The decoder would have to do something like this:

```
SomeClass decode(Dictionary<string,object> d) {
    var m = new SomeClass();
    m.par = (int)d["par"];
    m.levelData = ((List)d["level"]).Select(x => (int)x == 0 ? false : true).ToList();
    return m;
}
```

So, basically you must turn the (untyped) objects into typed values, and you have to do that explicitly. Note that here it is assumed that your list of zeroes and ones is homogeneous (i.e. does not contain "strange" values like strings, which would be perfectly legal in a dynamically typed language).

Comment: I notice that you don't specify a type for the List to contain here when you do `(List)d["level"]` I did not know that was possible, that helps.